# LaTeX Warnings: `' multiply defined and `@cref' multiply defined

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

By compiling a LaTeX file, I get the following messages:

```
`' multiply defined
```

And

```
`@cref' multiply defined
```

What could be generating this and how to fix it? Here is (a sample of) my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % I need this package

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,crefname={theorem}{theorems}]{theo}[2][]{%
breakable,enhanced,colback=blue!5!white,
colframe=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
coltitle=blue!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white},title=Theorem~\thetcbcounter~#2,label=#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\arabic*.,
ref=\color{blue}\bfseries\arabic*.]

\item\label{e1} My equation

\item\label{e2}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{theo}[]{}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\alph*)]
\item My \ref{e1} and \ref{e2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theo} 

\begin{theo}[]{}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\alph*)]
\item Again, my \ref{e1} and \ref{e2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theo} 

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified your `\newtcolorbox` to receive argument `label=#1`, which actually puts it into question whether this should be an optional argument, or if it should be properly handled as optional (I'll take the second stance below). And, on top of that, you called your created tcolorboxes with an empty optional argument, which means that the environments tried to create a label with an empty value, and since you use `cleveref`, a companion `@cref` reference is also created. Since you used the environment twice, both of them get to be multiply defined.

You'd better define the optional argument to be a final set of arbitrary options of your tcolorbox, instead of hardcoding it to `label=`.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % I need this package

\newtcolorbox[
  auto counter,
  number within=chapter,
  crefname={theorem}{theorems}
  ]{theo}[2][]{%
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=blue!5!white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
  coltitle=blue!25!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white},
  title=Theorem~\thetcbcounter~#2,
  #1 % this is the relevant change, instead of `label=#1'.
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\arabic*.,
ref=\color{blue}\bfseries\arabic*.]

\item\label{e1} My equation

\item\label{e2}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{theo}[label=theo1]{Important theorem}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\alph*)]
\item My \ref{e1} and \ref{e2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theo}

\begin{theo}[label=theo2]{Another theorem}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\alph*)]
\item Again, my \ref{e1} and \ref{e2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theo}

\cref{theo1,theo2}

% But you can also have an unlabeled one, if you need it.
\begin{theo}{Yet another theorem}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{blue}\bfseries\alph*)]
\item Again, my \ref{e1} and \ref{e2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```